# Prove that $9 \mid 4^n - 3n -1$ without using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n$ be a natural number.

I need to prove that $9 \mid 4^n-3n-1$

Could anyone give me some hints how to prove it without using induction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the binomial theorem, $4^n = (1+3)^n = 1 + 3n + 9a$.

Comment: This is not really "without induction" since the proof of the Binomial theorem is usually by induction on $\,n.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: can't we prove that via combinatorial arguments? But yes the most common proof is via induction.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$4^3=64\equiv 1\mod 9$$

Now divide to three cases, depending on $\left(n\mod 3\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach: consider the fact that
$$(4^{n}-1)-3n = (4-1)(1+4+\cdots+4^{n-1})-3n = 3[1+4+\cdots+4^{n-1} - n].$$

Comment: trivial error, but you missed out a $n$ in the second term of the middle (?) hand side. Just so others do not get confused.

Comment: Oh shoot, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_n=4^n-3n-1$

so $$u_{n+1}=4^{n+1}-3(n+1)-1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4(4^n-1)-3n$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4(4^n-1)- 4\cdot3n + 9n$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4(4^n - 3n - 1) + 9n$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4u_n + 9n$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4(4u_{n-1} + 9(n-1)) + 9n$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4^2u_{n-1} + 9(4(n-1) + n)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4^3u_{n-2} + 9(4^2(n-2) + 4(n-1) + n)$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4^nu_1 + 9\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k(n-k) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=4^n\cdot0 + 9\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k(n-k) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n+1}=9\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k(n-k) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow u_{n}=9\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}4^k(n-(k+1)) $$

$$\Rightarrow 9 \mid u_n \Rightarrow 9 \mid 4^n-3n-1$$